# MySQL fails to start at restart after Yosemite update

Tags: macos, mysql

I have MySQL installed. When I had the previous version, it used to start after boot automatically. This is not the case after I updated to Yosemite. In System Preferences there is an icon for MySQL and "Automatically Start MySQL Server on Startup" is checked. I tried unchecking - restart - check - restart still the same..

Everytime I boot the computer I will need to start it manually. Any fix?

Comment: Have you checked the system logs to see if there's anything there indicating why mysql is failing to load?

Comment: You should probably file a bug against this issue with MySQL. The fact that they are still attempting to use Startup Items, six major releases of OS X after `launchd` was introduced, is troubling to say the least.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL by default tries to use StartupItems.  That won't work with Yosemite.

I made a launchd control that is still compatible with the MySQL preferencepane.

Details here -
https://github.com/MacMiniVault/Mac-Scripts/blob/master/mmvMySQL/mmvmysql-Yosemite.md

Answer (score 1):

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476391/how-to-auto-load-mysql-on-startup-on-osx-yosemite)...

I've done this and it works. Pasted instructions below...

First, create a new file: `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist`

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true />
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
      <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>        
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then update permissions and add it to launchctl:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

The reason you need this is because the StartupItems have been removed from Yosemite. There is a note at the start of the page in Apple's docs explaining this: Startup items are a deprecated technology. Launching of daemons through this process may be removed or eliminated in a future release of OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to install MySQL with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), not from the .dmg available from the MySQL or Oracle. If you have Homebrew installed, simply run the following command in Terminal.

```
brew install mysql
```

Then to have MySQL start automatically, run the following:

```
brew services start mysql
```